# DAX Query to group column with getting its average of another column where date column is latest one

Tags: dax, azure-analysis-services

Let's say I have a table which contains school data with schoolName, StudentCount, Year columns.

What I want is get average of studentCount for latest year by school.

It may possible that school 1 's latest year is 2021 where as school 2 's latest year is 1990.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is probably late but I guess it can help someone.
The table is named SchoolData and the goal is to average the last record for each school across all schools.

[image]

```
DEFINE
VAR SchoolAndMaxYear = //LastYearForEachSchool
    GROUPBY (
        SchoolData,
        SchoolData[SchoolName],
        "YearValue", MAXX ( CURRENTGROUP (), SchoolData[YearValue] )
    )
VAR StudentCountForSchoolAndMaxYear =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        SchoolData,
        TREATAS ( SchoolAndMaxYear, SchoolData[SchoolName], SchoolData[YearValue] )
    )
EVALUATE StudentCountForSchoolAndMaxYear
EVALUATE
    ROW (
        "AVGStudentCountLyBySchool", AVERAGEX ( StudentCountForSchoolAndMaxYear, SchoolData[StudentCount] )
    )
```

[image]